# Add project to git tracking

Tags: git

I have a project that was not a git project. I have now turned it into one using a bitbucket service.

I have 6 other projects that will rely on this project and would like to know I can add git source control to them (without deleting them and starting with a fresh git clone / checkout)

So far I have tried copying the .git folder from a clone of the project in to one of the six other projects but when I run a "git pull" I get errors such as:

```
error: Could not read fe4cb2b279334e899b7c3b101cf55d50eca9bf29
```

Is there a way to "reset" the project and pull in all of the files to start tracking (the files are mostly the same anyway) without deleting or starting again in the six other projects?

I am sorry if this is confusing, I don't know how else to explain it, if anything needs clarifying please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the easiest way is to clone the new repo into a new folder, copy the other folder contents into that folder then copy the entire folder back over the top of the original (including the new .git information)